# subsetting data based with the condition of the current and previous entity in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have data with the `status` column. I want to subset my data to the condition of `'f'` status, and previous condition of `'f'` status.
to simplify:

```
df
id  status  time
1    n       1
1    n       2
1    f       3
1    n       4
2    f       1
2    n       2
3    n       1
3    n       2
3    f       3
3    f       4
```

my result should be:

```
id  status  time
1    n       2
1    f       3
2    f       1
3    n       2
3    f       3
3    f       4
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: It's not clear what logic you are using to remove rows. As far as "condition of previous entity", have you looked at `lag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` -

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(status == "f" | lead(status) == "f") %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id status  time
  <int> <fct>  <int>
1     1 n          2
2     1 f          3
3     2 f          1
4     3 n          2
5     3 f          3
6     3 f          4
```

Data -

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    status = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("f", "n"), class = "factor"), time = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "status", 
"time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```